# Jmeter Testplan - empty test plan error

Tags: java, jmeter

While importing a test plan, I see the error below:

```
2014/03/06 13:37:05 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: /Users/kiwitech/Desktop/load test jmeter/jouney_load_test .jmx 
2014/03/06 13:37:05 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='/Users/kiwitech/Desktop/load test jmeter' 
2014/03/06 13:37:05 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: com/jayway/jsonpath/InvalidPathException : com/jayway/jsonpath/InvalidPathException
---- Debugging information ----
message             : com/jayway/jsonpath/InvalidPathException
cause-exception     : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
cause-message       : com/jayway/jsonpath/InvalidPathException
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:100)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[6]/hashTree[5]/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
line number         : 348
version             : 2.11 r1554548
------------------------------- 
2014/03/06 13:37:05 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error org.apache.jmeter.exceptions.IllegalUserActionException: Empty TestPlan - see log file
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:174)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:136)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:92)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Please help me out with possible solutions. I have tried adding `commons lib` but its not helping me out.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like that your Test Plan containing [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) and your JMeter installation doesn't have this plug-in.

As per [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide

> You can [download the compiled JAR files](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/).  Select “Extras with libs set” from the download list.

Another option is

Comment: It could also be a JMeter version - JDK compliance issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue, trying to start JMeter 2.10 with Java 8. 
I switched to JMeter 5.0 in order to let it import correctly my .jmx file.